# Entity Framework 6 outputting related tables

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I just setup a new EF6 project. In my database I have 2 tables:
- languages
- langugesDescriptions
(with relation)

the context lazyLoadingEnabled is set to false.
(both on edmx as in code)

When getting data from languages: 
return context.languages
gives me on FIRST RUN, correct ouput, all language records.

But, when running context.languageDescriptions, and then again context.languages, in the output are also descriptions included.

any ideas? caching ?

Language class is auto generated: (under the .tt file)

```
Partial Public Class Language
    Public Property Lang_ID As Integer
    Public Property Lang_Name As String
    Public Property Lang_Code As String

    Public Overridable Property LanguageDescription As ICollection(Of LanguageDescription) = New HashSet(Of LanguageDescription)

End Class
```

Comment: How is your `Language` class look like? Does it contain a Navigation Property to `Descriptions`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internally, Entity Framework leverages the [Identity Map](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/identityMap.html) pattern which

> Ensures that each object gets loaded only once by keeping every loaded
>   object in a map. Looks up objects using the map when referring to
>   them.

When you're getting `Languages` from the context, then `LangaugesDescriptions`, EF knows that `LanguageDescriptions` is a Navigation-Property of `Language` so even if your Lazy-Loading is turned off, each loaded `Langauge` will contain its associated `LanguageDescriptions` because it's already loaded.

However, some will argue that `LanguageDescriptions` is actually a Value-Object and should not be exposed directly on your context, it should only be accessible as part of its (root entity) `Language`.

**Update (as per your comment):**

If you want to explicitly disable auto-filling of the `LanguageDescription` property, you can try to clear the local cache using:

```
context.LanguageDescription.Local.Clear()
```

You can also get the list of `LanguageDescription` using the `AsNoTracking()` method to prevent the entities from tracking each other:

```
context.LanguageDescription.AsNoTracking();
```

Or project the existing `Language` collection into a new collection that doesn't fill the `LanguageDescription` property:

```
From Lang In context.Languages
Select New Language With {
        .Lang_ID = Lang.Lang_ID,
        .Lang_Name = Lang.Lang_Name,
        .Lang_Code = Lang.Lang_Code,  
        }
```

Comment: And is there any way to disable that?

Comment: What is it that you're trying to achieve?

Comment: when calling context.languages, I only want the languages, not the descriptions.